# How do I fix this? (99 bottles of beer)

Tags: c++, string, warnings

I started studying Computer Science 2 months ago. I need help with this.

The compiler is giving me this warnings and my program isn't giving the number in words.

> Lab4Problem3.cpp:202:11: warning: multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]
>
> Lab4Problem3.cpp:202:26: warning: character constant too long for its type [enabled by default]
>
> Lab4Problem3.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
>
> Lab4Problem3.cpp:27:16: warning: the address of ‘std::string word_number(std::string, std::string)’ will always evaluate as ‘true’ [-Waddress]
>
> Lab4Problem3.cpp:29:16: warning: the address of ‘std::string word_number(std::string, std::string)’ will always evaluate as ‘true’ [-Waddress]

Here is what I have:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

string word_number(string units, string tens);
int num_entered;

int main ()
{

  char answer;

  do
    {

      cout << "Enter the number of bottles to throw on the wall: " << endl;
      cin >> num_entered;
      cout << endl;
  
      if (num_entered < 99 && num_entered >= 0)
    {

      while (num_entered > 0)
        {
           
          cout << word_number;
          cout << " bottles of beer on the wall,\n";
          cout << word_number;
          cout << " bottles of beer,\n"
           << "Take one down, pass it around.\n";
        
          num_entered--;
        }
      if (num_entered == 0)
        cout << "Zero bottles of beer on the wall" << endl;
    }
      else
    cout << "Invalid number!" << endl;

      cout << "Do you want to try it again? (Y/N)" << endl;
      cin >> answer;

    } while (answer =='Y' || answer=='y');

  return 0;

}


string word_number(string units, string tens)
{
  int tens_number, units_number;
  string result;

  if (num_entered < 20)
    {
      if(num_entered < 10)
    {
      units_number = num_entered;
      switch (units_number)
        {
        case 1:
          units =="One";
          break;
        case 2:
          units =="Two";
          break;
        case 3:
          units =="Three";
          break;
        case 4:
          units =="Four";
          break;
        case 5:
          units =="Five";
          break;
        case 6:
          units =="Six";
          break;
        case 7:
          units =="Seven";
          break;
        case 8:
          units =="Eight";
          break;
        case 9:
          units =="Nine";
          break;
        }

      return(units);

    }
      else
    units_number = num_entered%10;
      switch(units_number)
    {
    case 0:
      units =="Ten";
      break;
    case 1:
      units =="Eleven";
      break;
    case 2:
      units =="Twelve";
      break;
    case 3:
      units =="Thirteen";
      break;
    case 4:
      units =="Fourteen";
      break;
    case 5:
      units =="Fifteen";
      break;
    case 6:
      units =="Sixteen";
      break;
    case 7:
      units =="Seventeen";
      break;
    case 8:
      units =="Eighteen";
      break;
    case 9:
      units =="Nineteen";
      break;
    }
      return (units);
    }
  else
    tens_number = num_entered/10;
    units_number = num_entered%10;
  switch (tens_number)
    {
      /*case 0:
    tens == "Zero";
    break;*/
    case 1:
      tens =="Ten";
      break;
    case 2:
      tens =="Twenty";
      break;
    case 3:
      tens =="Thirty";
      break;
    case 4:
      tens =="Fourty";
      break;
    case 5:
      tens =="Fifty";
      break;
    case 6:
      tens =="Sixty";
      break;
    case 7:
      tens =="Seventy";
      break;
    case 8:
      tens =="Eighty";
      break;
    case 9:
      tens =="Ninety";
      break;
    }
    
  units_number = num_entered%10;
  
  switch (units_number)
    {
    case 1:
      units =="One";
      break;
    case 2:
      units =="Two";
      break;
    case 3:
      units =="Three";
      break;
    case 4:
      units =="Four";
      break;
    case 5:
      units =="Five";
      break;
    case 6:
      units =="Six";
      break;
    case 7:
      units =="Seven";
      break;
    case 8:
      units =="Eight";
      break;
    case 9:
      units =="Nine";
      break;
    }

    result = 'tens' + "-" + 'units';

 return result;

}
```

Comment: you have the problematic line(s), a clear error message, what's the problem?

Comment: Look up what `==` does in C++, and then look up what `=` does.

Comment: You have plenty of very fundamental syntax problems. Is this your first program using a function? I would recommend you to read more about variables, assignment, and function calls. And don't use global variables.

Comment: You're giving this problem a good shot.  Keep at it!  One thing I'd recommend is getting a more consistent indentation.  (I've seen far worse that what you've put here, so it's not bad.)  You may find it easier to read your code if you line up the left brace directly below the first character of your statements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems you're having problems with syntax here:

```
std::string word;
if (word == "One") {    // <-- this is comparison
   ...
}
word = "Two";           // <-- this is assignment
```

and when you do:

```
std::string result'
result = 'tens' + "-" + 'units';
```

`'tens'` and `'units'` are multi-byte characters rather than strings. What you should do there is:

```
std::string result;
result = tens + "-" + units;
```

Side note: Indentation of code is important. If it will be easier to read, it will be easier for you to work on it.

Comment: I think it's supposed to be `tens + "-" + units`, not `"tens-units"`

Comment: @JonathanWakely: Good point, I haven't noticed those string objects before.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you start by fixing the warnings?

> Lab4Problem3.cpp:202:11: warning: multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]

A character constant is one in single quotes. It must be a single character. That should be easy to fix, the compiler tells you which line it's on.

> Lab4Problem3.cpp:202:26: warning: character constant too long for its type [enabled by default]

This is caused by the same problem. Always fix the first diagnostics first, they might solve later ones too.

> Lab4Problem3.cpp:27:16: warning: the address of ‘std::string word_number(std::string, std::string)’ will always evaluate as ‘true’ [-Waddress]
>
> Lab4Problem3.cpp:29:16: warning: the address of ‘std::string word_number(std::string, std::string)’ will always evaluate as ‘true’ [-Waddress]

Again, the compiler tells you the line the problem is on. If you're trying to call the function `word_number` then that's not how you do it. Functions need arguments. That should be obvious too if you look at what you've written and think about how it can possibly work.

That won't make the program work, as your `word_number` function doesn't work, but you'll find out part of the problem if you fix the warnings.

Answer (score 1):

The first two errors are from this line:

```
    result = 'tens' + "-" + 'units';
```

I think you meant to concatenate the parameter variables, so it should be:

```
    result = tens + "-" + units;
```

The last two errors are from the two lines:

```
cout << word_number;
```

`word_number` is a function, you should be calling it, not trying to print the function itself (which just prints its address).

```
cout << word_number("something", "something_else");
```

I can't figure out what the parameters to this function are supposed to be used for. It seems like it should take `num_entered` as a parameter, not use the global variable.

Answer (score 0):

1. Assignment operator is a single '=' (`units =="One"` should be `units = "One"`)
2. Strings are enclosed in double quotes '"' (`result = 'tens' + "-" + 'units'` should be `result = string("tens") + "-" + "units"`

Answer (score 0):

The first warning concerns

```
result = 'tens' + "-" + 'units';
```

Python uses `'` for strings (or `"`) whereas C++ uses it for a single char.
Change the line to

```
result = std::string("tens") + "-" + "units";
```

Note: if you want to stream out the value of the variables `tens` this won't do what you require.

The next two warnings say you are using the address of a function here:

```
cout << word_number;
```

You probably intend to call the function

```
cout << word_number(num_entered, tens);
```

I'll leave the definition of `tens` as an exercise for the reader, but do notice you might be trying to set tens inside the function:

```
tens =="Ten";
```

You may mean

```
tens = "Ten";
```

If you want the function to change `tens` you might consider changing it to take a reference (and the same goes for units):

```
string word_number(string & units, string & tens);
```